# Python exception: ConnectionError 10054 An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

Tags: python, error-handling, connection

I don't have enough reputation yet to comment on another post so I'll ask it here. I am getting the "ConnectionError 10054 An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host" while doing a 'requests.get'. Now, I read this code on the other post but not sure if it is complete; can you please edit it so that it keeps retrying my 'requests.get' when the error comes up then exit of course when my 'requests.get' is successful. Thank you

```
import socket

retry_count = 5  # this is configured somewhere

for retries in range(retry_count):
    try:
        data1 = requests.get(url)
        return True
    except (error_reply, error_perm, error_temp):
        return False
    except socket.gaierror, e:
        if e.errno != 10054:
            return False
        reconnect()
return False
```

Getting error;
    return True
    ^
SyntaxError: 'return' outside function

Answer (score 2):

The reason why you are having an error is simple. You haven't made a function, so you can't call return. The simplest way to fix this is using a `break` which allows you to jump out of the loop. Here's an example of using `break` in your code.

```
import socket
import requests
retry_count = 5
for retries in range(retry_count):
    try:
        data1 = requests.get(url)
        #Jumps Out Of Loop
        break
    except (socket.gaierror, requests.ConnectionError) as e:
        if e.errno != 10054:
            continue
        reconnect()
#Does Something If Loop Never Breaks
else:
  print("Couldn't Connect")
```

Comment: Hello,thank you but I get an error;     if e.errno != 10054:
                                                                 ^
TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation      and I had to change this except socket.gaierror as e:

Comment: also, I am not currently getting the 10054 error so I can make a fake url so i get a 11001 error instead to test but getting the TabError on that line.

Comment: I added #if e.errno != 10054: and put if e.errno != 11001: but get an error -  except (error_reply, error_perm, error_temp):
NameError: name 'error_reply' is not defined

Comment: Okay, I was originally using your code to try and give you a reason why the return error was happening. The current errors you are getting are a result of that. The error_reply, error_perm, and error_temp exceptions don't exist, so I just took them out. I edited my code to make a better example.

Comment: Okay, cool, so now I'm just going to test it with a fake url to get me a 11001 error instead, so where can I put another print("Couldn't Connect") command to make sure that the function is working correctly? I put it just above the continue command but I just get a Tab/Space error. Thank you

Comment: If you want to make it so that your client will reconnect, then you can just add `and e.errno != 11001`, and if you want to make it so that your client just quits, then you can just add an `if e.errno  == 11001` inside the original if statement to catch when the errno is 11001.

Also, the reason why you are getting the tab-space error is because your text editor is set to use tabs when you hit the tab button, which is not correct according to https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/, which is basically the style guide for python.

Comment: Okay, I fixed the TAB issue but I don't think it is working. I added a Time sleep of 100 before every retry and another print statement but it finishes real quick '1/2 second' still with the 11001 error and I don't see the print statement either. Did I do something wrong. Here is what I have;  except (socket.gaierror, requests.ConnectionError) as e:
   if e.errno != 11001:
    continue
   print("Website unavailable... retrying")
   time.sleep(100)
   reconnect()        even if I put retry_count=10000 the script still finishes in 1/2 second

Comment: That's because your if statement should be `if e.errno == 11001`. Also, `continue` will skip anything after it.

Comment: Hello, but you said "make it so that your client just quits, then you can just add an if e.errno == 11001" Does that mean it exits and doesn't retry the retry_count? I'll run some tests, I put it before the continue but it still didn't sleep or print anything. Weird

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166208/discussion-between-brian-ton-and-matrixebiz).